# Calling an excel function from oracle forms

Tags: oracle, excel, oracleforms

Can anyone suggest how I can use ole2 to perform an excel function (e.g. PMT()), from oracle forms and get back the result??

Comment: which version of Forms are you using?  This sort of integration was pretty straightforward in the older client/server implementation (4.5 - 6.5) but trickier in the web-delivered versions.

Answer (score 2):

I created PL/SQL functions that will calculate the PMT function per the formula that is in MS Excel.

This first function doesn't factor in the future value, the second does.

```
/* No future value factor */
FUNCTION pmt (APR     IN NUMBER /* Rate (APR) */,
                  pv      IN NUMBER /* Loan amount */,
                  nper    IN NUMBER /* number of payments */
                  ) RETURN NUMBER IS /* periodic payment amount */
BEGIN
    RETURN  (APR / (1 - power((1 + APR),-nper)) * pv );

END pmt;    

/* With future value factor */
FUNCTION pmt (APR    IN NUMBER, /* Rate (APR) */
              nper   IN NUMBER, /* Number of payments */
              pv     IN NUMBER, /* present value */
              fv     IN NUMBER  /*future value */
             ) RETURN NUMBER IS /* periodic payment amount */

  calcpmt NUMBER := 0;
  powercalc NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN

 powercalc:= POWER(1+APR, nper);
 RETURN APR / (powercalc - 1) * -(pv * powercalc + fv);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just recreate the PMT function in PL/SQL, the native language of forms. E.g. based on http://forums.contractoruk.com/technical/28716-calculate-apr-loan-repayment-using-pl-sql-java.html:

```
CREATE
FUNCTION pmt (rate     IN NUMBER /* Rate (APR) */
             ,amt      IN NUMBER /* Loan amount */
             ,payments IN NUMBER /* number of payments */
             ) RETURN NUMBER IS /* periodic payment amount */
BEGIN
  RETURN (rate/12*amt*power((1+rate/12),payments))/(power((1+rate/12),payments)-1);
END pmt;
```

e.g.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(
   'PMT = $' || TRUNC( pmt(0.249, 5000, 11), 2)
  );
END;
/

PMT = $513.07
```